# How to decode input flags of system calls in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am trying to trace system calls in Linux using some tools like Pin or DynamoRIO. From these tools I can see what system calls are executed and what is the value of input arguments and also return value. But some system calls like `access` have an integer value that might be bitwise-OR'ed of some other integer values.

For example in access system call, `mode` can be `F_OK`, `R_OK`, `W_OK`, or `X_OK` or bitwise-OR of two or more of them.

```cpp
int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
```

How can I decode an integer value (that I know has passed to system call as input) to see what flags are enabled in a system call?

Comment: You might want to look at the source of `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to the function is already known by the passer, who is you. Moreover, their integer values may vary from machine to machine owing to its architecture or operating system. On my Apple machine, `unistd.h` involves the following.

```
/* access function */
#define F_OK            0       /* test for existence of file */
#define X_OK            (1<<0)  /* test for execute or search permission */
#define W_OK            (1<<1)  /* test for write permission */
#define R_OK            (1<<2)  /* test for read permission */
```

As you understand, they are `0000`, `0001`, `0010`, `0100`, respectively. Now, you can manipulate them by bitwising. You need to inspect inside of header file in which there are the constants used.